# How do i merge an audio netstream and a video netstream into one republished netstream using flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, merge, flex3, red5, netstream

I have two netstreams:

1. audio published in red5
2. video also published in red5

Now I'm a flex3 application and I need a way to be able to attach the audio of stream 1, and the video of stream 2 to a new netstream and just publish it.

How do I do that? NetStream will only allow me to attach Camera or Microphone...

Answer (score 1):

my friend I think you can merge both stream in one with FFMPEG command. But their compression mighg be an problem.
If you have record two stream separately than you can play them both in AS3 with the help of 
Netstream class but remember Audio always comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Well here are two links.. that may help you capture your screen 
AIR 2.0 Native Process - Part 1 mentioned at http://gotoandlearn.com/

and second is for audio/video recording
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html

i have worked on both linked and captured screen and audio from headphone and then merged it with FFMPEG ..